# Why does my homebutton doesn't resize according to my CSS attribute?

Tags: css

This is how i link my CSS with my entire masterpage in Visual Studio

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />
```

This is how my homebutton is being created.

```
<div id="homebutton">
<input type="image" src="image/logo.jpg">
</div>
```

And this is how my CSS look like

```
#homebutton {
   position:absolute;
   left:0%;
   top:0%;
   margin: 0px;
   height:70px;
}
```

However, when i change the height to any pixel, the homebutton's size still remain the same. Up to now i still dont know why.

Comment: Make the image bigger, increase of height does only act on the DIV height. For better understanding use a background color in your DIV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because you are changing height of div.. you must change height of input

```
#homebutton input[type=image]
{
   height:80px;
}
```

Comment: Honestly i'm new to CSS and it's my first time seeing input as well. Thanks ^-^

Answer (score 1):

Since you are changing the height of the `<div>` the home button is in, the size of the home-button (which is a jpeg) does not change, as it does not auto-fit the surrounding `<div>`.

You have to add own style information to the `<input>`-Tag! Otherwise, scaling the jpeg is not a good idea, as it becomes blurry - you'll have to use a bigger graphic or a SVG